# Renomear arquivos de uma pasta de forma sequencial - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Como seria possível renomear arquivos do mesmo formato mas com nomes diferentes (por exemplo: Imagens) para um padrão sequencial ?

Exemplo:

**De**

```
titulo-capa.jpg | foto-perfil.jpg | background.jpg
```

**Para**

```
imagem01.jpg | imagem02.jpg | imagem03.jpg
```

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca/código/extensão (JS/JQuery) que me permita fazer isso ?

Comment: Tenta usar `node.js` conforme descrito [nesse post da comunidade internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504566/renaming-files-using-node-js)

Comment: `angularjs` com certeza não serve pra isso, com js via navegador, acho que não é possível, mas você pode fazer o upload das fotos e baixá-las com um nome diferente, porém iria para a pasta configurada no navegador (normalmente, `downloads`) e não iria excluir os arquivos originais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `node.js` como o Leonardo mencionou.

- Requira a biblioteca `file-system`.

  ```
  const fs = require("fs")
  ```
- Em seguida, você pode obter um array com o nome e a extensão de todos os arquivos de um diretório usando a função `readdir()`.

  ```
  // Como usar a função
  fs.readdir(path,callback)

  // isso vai retornar todos os arquivos do diretório raíz
  fs.readdir("./",(err,files)=>{
      console.log(files)
  })
  ```
- Após isso, use a função `forEach()` no array para executar uma ação em cada arquivo.

  ```
  // Como usar a função
  array.forEach(function(element,index,array))

  // Código
  fs.readdir("./raw_images",(err,files)=>{
      files.forEach((file,index)=>{

      })
  })
  ```
- Use a função `copyFile()` para copiar os arquivos para outro diretório (vale lembrar que a função `copyFile()` não cria novos diretórios, para isso você precisa usar a função `mkdir()`.

  ```
  // Como usar a função
  fs.copyFile(src,dest)

  // Código
  fs.readdir("./raw_images",(err,files)=>{
      files.forEach((file,index)=>{
          fs.copyFile(`./raw_images/${file}`,`./raw_images/new_images/imagem${index})
      })
  })
  ```
- Porém, desta forma, o `fs` irá criar um arquivo sem extensão, então você deve capturar a extensão desse arquivo para poder copia-lo da forma correta.

  ```
  // Gera um novo array onde o . é o critério para separar os valores ("meu-arquivo.jpeg" vai se tornar ["meu-arquivo","jpeg"]
  var extension = file.split(".")
  // Salva apenas o último elemento do array
  extension = extension[extension.length-1]
  ```
- O cógido vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

  ```
  fs.readdir("./raw_images",(err,files)=>{
      files.forEach((file,index)=>{
          var extension = file.split(".")
          extension = extension[extension.length-1]

          fs.copyFile(`./raw_images/${file}`,`./raw_images/new_images/imagem${index}.${extension}`)

      })

  })
  ```

Espero ter ajudado c: